# Interactive image for markdown cell

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, png

I want to prepare an image to be used in Jupyter in markdown cell. The image should have frames to go interactively through. An image can be produced in some graphical program with layers.

I tried to get a png image with Sketches program and with layers